# a required file variable cannot be called on require

Tags: php

when i try to call a variable from another file on require, it sets to undefined variable.

Example Scenario : I have a file called settings where i have a variable called $folder and set to a string. When i require that variable in another file, $setting variable becomes an undefined variable.

However when in remote host it takes the variable from another file. but in a local XAMPP environment it does not.

It might be a simple issue but searching i could not find a proper answer on this.

Notice: Undefined variable: folder in C:\xampp\htdocs\abc\admin\modules\settings\module.php on line 28

config.php

```
@security();

$settings = siteSettings();

$folder = "settings";
```

module.php

```
    require "config.php";

require "modules/".$folder."/manage.php";
```

Comment: how about some code?

Comment: the error says the value not set to the variable.

Comment: Could it be that you define the variable inside of some conditional logic like an if statement? That could potentially be the issue, if your code never enters the if, the variable doesn't get declared

Comment: @user3005775 , i've added the snippet

Comment: @FMashiro, no it is just a variable declared.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like You have a different settings in both environments. You could figure out differences or You could try define variable in one file as a constant and use in another.

```
define('_MY_FOLDER', 'tmp0');
```

Use it in another file like

```
echo _MY_FOLDER;
```

Also You can check if it is defined to be sure.

Comment: hello guys i found what was going wrong. In a local environment i had to specify the relative path to the file. eg : ../admin/modules/settings/config.php and it recognized the file. however in the remote host just require config worked. Strange but that was the difference.

Answer (score 0):

actually there is no reason it shouldn't work try

```
require("config.php");

require("modules/".$folder."/manage.php");
```

Comment: there may also be an xamp setting you are missing, in your php.ini , you may need to change allow_url_include, i have not had this problem on my localhost, but I don't use xamp so it may be different requirements on yours

Comment: hello guys i found what was going wrong. In a local environment i had to specify the relative path to the file. eg : ../admin/modules/settings/config.php and it recognized the file. however in the remote host just require config worked. Strange but that was the difference.

Answer (score 0):

hello guys i found what was going wrong. In a local environment i had to specify the relative path to the file. eg : ../admin/modules/settings/config.php and it recognized the file. however in the remote host just require config worked. Strange but that was the difference.